# How to handle multiple button clicks in javafx?

Tags: event-handling, mouseevent, javafx-8, buttonclick

I made a rubiks cube and its animations are working fine until I press the button for a move before the ending of the animation of a previous move. This is quite reasonable. At first I click a button for a particular move and it rotates as per my code for the button's corresponding event handling method. Now if I press the next button for the next desired move after the previous animation is finished everything goes fine. But if I press the button for the next move while animation of the previous move is on action, then my cube becomes distorted. This is so becuase two separate animations are being simultaneously played on the same cube(s) ( If I am wrong about this reason, please correct me ). In order to prevent this I want to store the button event in a queue in the sequence they are clicked and execute them one after the other after the correspomding animations of each are over. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Having an event queue looks a bit too complex for the task. Did you considered an option to ignore all clicks until the animation is finished?

Comment: Yeah my sencond option if I cant achieve this is disabling all buttons so long as the animation is in action.